# What is the difference between 1x2 and 1x3 image gradient kernel filter definition

Tags: image-processing, filtering, gradient, edge-detection

Recently I have a debate with my colleague on image gradient operation.

Normally, the image gradient is defined as:

`dI_dx(j,k) = I(j,k+1) - I(j,k)  # x partial derivative of image`

`dI_dy(j,k) = I(j+1,k) - I(j,k)  # y partial derivative of image`

For x partial derivative of image, this operation can be represented by a 1x2 filter array:

`[1 -1]`

But there is also another definition:

`dI_dx(j,k) = I(j,k+1) - I(j,k-1)` => `[1 0 -1]` (filter array)

**So my colleague asked: What is the difference between them, and why is the latter 1x3 filter
more often used than the 1x2 filter?**

We have discussed some possible reasons:

1. 1x3 sampling is more robust than 1x2

   My colleague : No, they both sample 2 pixels for each image gradient pixel, the probability that a noise occurs on the sampled pixels is the same among these filters.
2. 1x3 is smoother than 1x2

   My colleague : No, the definition of the 1x2 and 1x3 filters are not smoothed at all.
   The Sobel filter is the one smoothed by a gaussian...

Extended question: **Does image gradient's spatial filter kernel have so called "window size"?**

By the way, I and my colleague are not persuaded by the following reference webpage...

http://www.cis.rit.edu/people/faculty/rhody/EdgeDetection.htm

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078131

Answer (score 2):

One way to examine these filters in the context of digital filter design, specifically an ideal FIR differentiator.  The ideal digital differentiator has an antisymmetric unit sample response h(n)=-h(-n) and hence h(0)=0.  Thus [1 0 -1] is closer to the ideal differentiator than [1 -1].  Take a look at any DSP reference for more theory.  In practice I always use a smoothed derivative with the Sobel operator.

Answer (score 1):

The 1x2 filter will produce samples that lie between the inputs, while the 1x3 filter output will line up with the input. However the 1x2 filter will capture finer detail.